# Javascript keydown timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, timing, onkeydown

I am working on a very time-sensitive application that uses key presses for user input. As I am talking milliseconds here, I went ahead and tried a version like this:

```js
function start() {
  //stim.style.display = "block";
  rt_start = new Date().getTime();
  response_allowed = 1;
}

function end() {
  var t = rt_end - rt_start;
  //stim.style.display = "none";
  log.innerHTML = t;
  i++;
  if (i < iterations) {
    setTimeout('start();', 1000);
  }
}

var rt_start;
var rt_end;
var iterations = 100;
var i = 0;
var response_allowed = 0;
var stim;
var log;
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (response_allowed == 1) {
      rt_end = new Date().getTime();
      response_allowed = 0;
      end();
    }
  };
  stim = document.getElementById('stim');
  log = document.getElementById('log');
  start();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cfefd93404e6b0eb3cde02b4b6df4e2b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" id="stim" />
```

And it works fine, usually sub-5ms timers (just holding down a key). But as soon as I modify the code to display the image (uncommenting the two lines), this slows down a lot to about 30ms.

Can someone point me into the direction why exactly this is the case and how to possibly avoid this additional delay?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Side note: There's almost never any reason to pass strings into `setTimeout`/`setInterval`, and several reasons *not* to. Instead, pass in a reference to the function you want to call: `setTimeout(start, 1000);`

Comment: jsfiddle does not seem to work due to the setTimeout? At least I couldn't get it to work earlier, sorry.  The passing of the string is due to my approach of passing multiple functions/actions in the original script, e.g. displaying a div, changing its content etc. These are various actions chained together. Edit: The actions are highly variable, so there is no way of having a defined function for each.

Comment: @KarstenSender: jsFiddle's fine with `setTimeout` (http://jsfiddle.net/gcvtaxfm/), but I've updated your question to turn your code into a Stack Snippet (I used your gravatar instead of `test.png`).

Comment: FWIW, with the version above, holding down a key gives me values in the ~23ms range. (Holding a key down means we're waiting on keyrepeat, doesn't it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) where available (with a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5438650) for browsers that don't provide it).

It's a high-resolution timestamp (designed with accurate measurement in mind) to be used (e.g.) with the Navigation Timing and Web Performance APIs (search for this in the Mozilla Developer Network, as I can't share more than two links within a single post).

The *quick* way to get a DOMHighResTimeStamp - much like you do with `var ts = new Date().getTime();` to get a regular millisecond timestamp - is:

`var ts = performance.now();`

As I said above, take a look at the Web Performance API at MDN. It will be very helpful if your application is really time-sensitive.

EDIT:

About your snippet, it seems to me that if you hold a key down, you will be always limited to the resolution of the keydown event (which fires continuously, but not every milissecond). You can easily see this behavior if you press a character key down (continuously) with a text editor and check for how many times per second the character is *written*. This, I guess, is controlled via an OS setting.

You are also limited to the "drift" associated with setTimeout/setInterval. You see, setTimeout queues *something* for execution after a *given delay*, but it does not guarantee timely execution. It's a "best effort" scenario and, if the browser is busy doing something, it will drift significantly. Meaning: if you use a setTimeout to re-enable a `response_allowed` variable after 1 second, you can expect it to re-enable it after "about" (but not exactly) 1 second.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tested performance.now() already, but it seems to induce a higher load than Date.now() (see http://jsperf.com/date-now-vs-new-date-gettime/34). The delay of the setTimeout should be of no issue here, as I only start the timing within the function - thus ignoring the (more or less) 1000ms between iterations. The bigger issue might, as @TJCrowder mentioned, that there are delays within the keydown event. This has been (somewhat) confirmed and fixed through an applet called Keydrown (http://jeremyckahn.github.io/keydrown/). Thanks!